# Error retrieving https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/json/cve/1.0/nvdcve-1.0-2020.meta; received response code 404

Tags: docker, gradle, dependencies, gitlab

I am using gradle:5.6.2-jdk8 docker image in gitlab pipeline.

```
gradle clean build
```

Above command is failing with error:
 Unable to download meta file: https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/json/cve/1.0/nvdcve-1.0-2020.json.gz
        No documents exist

Only link related to this problem I found is:
https://github.com/jeremylong/DependencyCheck/issues/2039

There isn't any solution available

Answer (score 2):

Too early this year ?

2019 json is there : https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/json/cve/1.0/nvdcve-1.0-2019.json.gz

2020 version seems to not have been created yet or has another url...

Some hints there https://github.com/jeremylong/DependencyCheck/issues/2403

This is a duplicate of [How to ignore Maven dependency-check failure on missing nvd file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59555889/how-to-ignore-maven-dependency-check-failure-on-missing-nvd-file)

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59555889/how-to-ignore-maven-dependency-check-failure-on-missing-nvd-file

Comment: If the question is a duplicate, flag it as such instead of answering and/or mentioning what it duplicates

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24992412)

Comment: @pl_prof ,
I got the error and googled, I didn't find any StackOverflow link. That's why I asked this question.

Comment: @camille flag to close as duplicate requires reputation 15 what i have not yet.

Comment: Take a look again at the [guidance on reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). If you don't have enough rep to do something like flag or comment, rack up a little more by answering & asking good questions. If anything, leaving low quality answers can backfire, since you'll lose rep if they get downvoted

Answer (score 1):

2020 version is now available

https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/json/cve/1.0/nvdcve-1.0-2020.json.gz

Answer (score 0):

You can add this inside dependencyCheck in build.gradle

```
    cve{
        urlBase='https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/json/cve/1.1/nvdcve-1.1-%d.json.gz'
        urlModified='https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/json/cve/1.1/nvdcve-1.1-modified.json.gz'
    }
```